# counting multiple Array elements

Tags: c++

i wrote a C++ program which shows me the number of repetition of array elements ...my source code is :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int x[20] = {1,1,32,43,54,65,76,76,76,2,12,12,32,43,54,3,3,23,1,43};
    for (int i=0;i<20;i++) {
    }

    for (int i=0;i<20;i++) {
        int count=1;
        for (int j=i+1;j<19;j++) { 
            if (x[i]==x[j]) count++;
        }
        cout<<"The number "<<x[i]<<" is repeated "<<count<<" times"<<"\n";
    }
}
```

and out put of this is :

```
The number 1 is repeated 3 times
The number 1 is repeated 2 times
The number 32 is repeated 2 times
The number 43 is repeated 2 times
The number 54 is repeated 2 times
The number 65 is repeated 1 times
The number 76 is repeated 3 times
The number 76 is repeated 2 times
The number 76 is repeated 1 times
The number 2 is repeated 1 times
The number 12 is repeated 2 times
The number 12 is repeated 1 times
The number 32 is repeated 1 times
The number 43 is repeated 1 times
The number 54 is repeated 1 times
The number 3 is repeated 2 times
The number 3 is repeated 1 times
The number 23 is repeated 1 times
The number 1 is repeated 1 times
The number 43 is repeated 1 times
```

the problem is output shows array element each time but i want that my program just shows the repeated array just for once. and i don't want to define new array .. Anyone have a clue about what's going on ??

Note : that without definition any new array and without sorting program output should be like this :

```
    The number 1 is repeated 3 times
    The number 32 is repeated 2 times
    The number 43 is repeated 3 times
    The number 54 is repeated 2 times
    The number 65 is repeated 1 times
    The number 76 is repeated 3 times
    The number 2 is repeated 1 times
    The number 12 is repeated 2 times
    The number 3 is repeated 2 times
    The number 23 is repeated 1 times
```

Comment: why the output should not contain `The number 3 is repeated 2 times` ?

Comment: *"without definition any new array and without sorting"* -- Why? Don't place arbitrary restrictions on the solutions to your problem, then your problem has nothing to do with real world programming.

Comment: Do you want to print the number of elements which are only there for more than once? And not print the one which is there for once?

Comment: Please show the exact __expected__ output.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Ok i have edited output

Comment: You need to store those values somewhere and check if they are equal to `1` or not. `std::map` is the likely candidate for the task. Or perform simple checks: `if (count > 1) { print; }`

Comment: @SinaSameti your algorithm is simply wrong. Debug this with a very small set (like `int x[4] = { 1,1,32,43 };`) and you'll understand

Answer (score 4):

You can use a map to count your elements, which satisfies your requirement that you do not create a new array.

```
std::map<int, int> counts;
for(auto&& elem : x)
{
    counts[elem]++;
}

for(auto&& item : counts)
{
    std::cout << "The number " << item.first << " is repeated " << item.second << " times; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a **reduce** operation. C++ have a left-fold operation called `std::accumulate` in algorithms. Feed it with a `std::map` to create a count record.

```
auto count_map = std::accumulate(std::begin(x), std::end(x),
                                 std::map<int, int>{},
                                 [] (auto& m, int val) -> decltype(m) {
    ++m[val];
    return m;
});

// Output result
for (auto&& [val, count] : count_map) {
    std::cout << "Value: " << val << " - Count: " << count << std::endl;
}
```

```
# Output:
Value: 1 - Count: 3
Value: 2 - Count: 1
Value: 3 - Count: 2
Value: 12 - Count: 2
Value: 23 - Count: 1
Value: 32 - Count: 2
Value: 43 - Count: 3
Value: 54 - Count: 2
Value: 65 - Count: 1
Value: 76 - Count: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

Without extra structures, you may simply do:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    const int x[20] = {1,1,32,43,54,65,76,76,76,2,12,12,32,43,54,3,3,23,1,43};

    for (int i=0;i<20;i++) {
        if (std::find(x, x + i, x[i]) != x + i) {
            continue;
        }
        const auto count = std::count(x + i, x + 20, x[i]);
        std::cout << "The number " << x[i] << " is repeated " << count << " times\n";
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/WujtcL)

Comment: your code does not shows array 65 and arrays with 1 occurrence

Comment: @SinaSameti: My first version only printed when `count > 1`, it has been fixed, and demo added.

Comment: thank you for your answer it goes well in code runner but it has error in Borland C++ compiler...how can i run it on borland C++?

Comment: I suspect problem is with `auto`. you may use `int` instead.

Comment: error in borland C++ is : could not find a match for std::count(const int *,const int *,const int *)

Comment: Try to store `x[i]`in intermediate variable.